# Powershell returns different datatype depending on number of elements

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

Currently I'm very confused with Powershell and how it handles Arrays/ArrayLists and PSObjects/CustomObjects.

High level:

I'm trying to Import a CSV file and inserting at specific lines "placeholder" entries. This is actually working fine. My only issue the moment is, in case the CSV contains only 1 Element (Line) Powershell Creates a `PsCustomObject`. If there are multiple lines, Powershell delivers an Array.

1 Element in `$pConnectionsOnMpDevice

```
$pConnectionsOnMpDevice  = ($pList | ?({$_.device -like "*$pDevice*"}))
($pConnectionsOnMpDevice).getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name BaseType
True True PsCustomObject[] System.Object
```

n Element in `$pConnectionsOnMpDevice`

```
$pConnectionsOnMpDevice  = ($pList | ?({$_.device -like "*$pDevice*"}))
($pConnectionsOnMpDevice).getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name BaseType
True True Object[] System.Array
```

Finally I try to add an Element:

```
$pConnectionsOnMpDevice += $MpObject
```

(One of my first approaches was to use (FYI):

```
#$pConnectionsOnMpDevice.Insert($index,$match)
```

If I try to add `$MpObject` to `$pConnectionsOnMpDevice` I get following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\Scripts\PS_GenerateMPConfig\PS_GenerateMPConfig_06_f.ps1:90 char:13
+             $pConnectionsOnMpDevice += $MpObject
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I assume it's the same issue as described [here](http://blog.tyang.org/2011/02/24/powershell-functions-do-not-return-single-element-arrays/)

I tried to cast `$pConnectionsOnMpDevice` to an `Arraylist` by:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]::$pConnectionsOnMpDevice  += $MpObject
```

But still no success.

Does anyone has an advice how I can add an element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the array subexpression operator (`@()`) to force a value expression to return an array:

```
$pConnectionsOnMpDevice  = @($pList | ?({$_.device -like "*$pDevice*"}))
```

---

> I tried to cast $pConnectionsOnMpDevice to an Arraylist by:
>
> ```
> [System.Collections.ArrayList]::$pConnectionsOnMpDevice  += $MpObject
> ```

That's not a cast, that's a static invocation - PowerShell will invoke whatever static method or property has the same name as `"$pConnectionOnMpDevice"`.

Remove the `::` if you want a cast operation:

```
$array = 1,2,3
$arraylist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$array
```

Comment: Mathias, 

Thank you so much for you help. Small Change but successfull :)